MarkLogic- TCP Connection timeout issue during MarkLogic - Roxy deployment
We have recently migrated the cluster from Classic Load Balancer (CLB) to Application Load Balancer (ALB) and tried to deploy the XQuery modules using Roxy along XDBC/XCC with an SSL enabled port. We are now getting TCP connection timeout issue and can't deploy.
Note: we are able to execute from postman with HTTP 200 successful status.
The previous Classic Load balancer configuration - We have used TCP protocol listener configuration as it was working. Attached following screenshot for your reference:

Now with the Application Load Balancer configuration, we have used HTTPS protocol in the listener configuration as its allowing only HTTPS & HTTP.
We have used the ruby Version 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]
Below is the Error Log while deploying using Roxy framework

(base) 214691@AMBIN07363 atom-marklogic % ./ml dev-aws deploy modules
-v [POST]  mydomain.com:8000/v1/eval (Protocol- https) Login for admin user:xxxxxx Password for vvasan user:  [POST]
mydomain.com:8000/v1/eval (Protocol- https) source permissions:
[{:capability=>"E", :role=>"mdm-role"}, {:capability=>"R",
:role=>"mdm-role"}, {:capability=>"U", :role=>"mdm-role"}] Deploying
application configurations deploying application configuration
src/app/config/config.xqy with name /config.xqy on mdm-modules Login
for admin user:xxxx loading: /config.xqy => /app/config/config.xqy
[PUT]
mydomain.com:8034/insert?uri=%2Fapp%2Fconfig%2Fconfig.xqy&perm=Emdm-role&perm=Rmdm-role&perm=Umdm-role&tzoffset=19800&dbname=mdm-modules
Roxy::Http : request failure count: 1, exception: #<Net::OpenTimeout:
execution expired>
Roxy::Http : request failure count: 2, exception: #<Net::OpenTimeout:
execution expired> Roxy::Http : request failure count: 3, exception:
#<Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired> Roxy::Http : request failure count: 4, exception: #<Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired> Roxy::Http
: re-raising same error: mydomain.com temporarily unavailable:
(execution expired) -- error count: 4, error age: 0
deploy/lib/ml.rb:176: warning: constant Net::HTTPServerException is
deprecated ERROR: mydomain.com temporarily unavailable: (execution
expired) ERROR:
["/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/RoxyHttp.rb:362:in
block in request'", "/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/RoxyHttp.rb:352:in loop'",
"/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/RoxyHttp.rb:352:in
request'", "/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/MLClient.rb:113:in go'",
"/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/xcc.rb:175:in
go'", "/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/xcc.rb:156:in load_buffer'",
"/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/server_config.rb:2160:in
block (2 levels) in deploy_src'", "/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/server_config.rb:2144:in each'",
"/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/server_config.rb:2144:in
block in deploy_src'", "/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/server_config.rb:2118:in each'",
"/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/server_config.rb:2118:in
deploy_src'", "/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/server_config.rb:2083:in deploy_modules'",
"/Users/214691/Documents/GitHub/atom-marklogic/deploy/lib/server_config.rb:1190:in
deploy'", "deploy/lib/ml.rb:166:in '"]


Was it working before with Roxy deployments to a SSL enabled XDBC appserver through the CLB? Does it work if you point directly to a MarkLogic node and skip over the ALB? Does it work if you change it not to be SSL enabled (not suggesting permanently, just to test if it issue is TLS)

What version of MarkLogic are you using? And is port 8034 an XDBC app server, or a (so-called enhanced) HTTP app server with XDBC capabilities?

This seems relevant by the way: https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/issues/862. Looks like it got fixed in the develop branch, but not in master.

Looking at the Roxy xcc.rb module, it seems that it always hard-codes http://
https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/blob/master/deploy/lib/xcc.rb#L115
r = go "http://#{options[:host]}:#{options[:port]}/eval", "post", headers, params

You said that you are using TLS, so it should be https://
You might also need to set @use_xcc to false or change the header from "XDBC/1,0" to "HTTP/1..1", which is what happens in Java when you set xcc.httpcompliant in the Java XCC library.
https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/blob/master/deploy/lib/xcc.rb#L39

Hi Mads Hansen, Thanks for providing suggestion.
We have seen that eval url is working fine in port # 8000 (i.e  URL : https://dev.aws.ml.warnerbros.com:8000/v1/eval )
We are facing issue on XDBC port # 8034 which is used to insert the files through Roxy deployment.
i.e  (URL :[PUT]   https://dev.aws.ml.warnerbros.com:8034/insert?uri=%2Fapp%2Fconfig%2Fconfig.xqy&perm=Emdm-role&perm=Rmdm-role&perm=Umdm-role&tzoffset=19800&dbname=mdm-modules)

i.e  (URL :[PUT]   https://dev.aws.ml.warnerbros.com:8034/insert?uri=%2Fapp%2Fconfig%2Fconfig.xqy&perm=Emdm-role&perm=Rmdm-role&perm=Umdm-role&tzoffset=19800&dbname=mdm-modules)
Already, we have added https in the xcc.rb file_ line #179 which is used to insert the file, the below mentioned url working fine in postman.
def build_load_uri(target_uri, options, commit)
url = "https://#{@hostname}:#{@port}/insert?"

Have you tried pointing directly to a MarkLogic server, bypassing the ALB?

Wondering if you might also need to set @use_xcc to false or change the header from "XDBC/1,0" to "HTTP/1..1" https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/blob/master/deploy/lib/xcc.rb#L39 which is what happens in Java when you set xcc.httpcompliant

Hi Mads Hansen, We have updated the header from "XDBC/1.0" to "HTTP/1.1" in xcc.rb file and tried deployment now facing issue with below error message. Anyidea? what causing this issue, Thank you.
Error Message
XDMP-DOCROOTTEXT: Invalid root text "049120&#10;&#10;" at /admin/assets/webfonts/Cabin-Bold-webfont.svg line 3

That looks like it's trying to parse the response as XML, but it's not well-formed XML content. Possibly double-escaped content where &#10; was turned into &amp;#10;

we have updated the respected xml file and tried again with roxy deployment, facing issue with 504 bad Gateway time out issue or internal server issue

Might need to either bump the timeouts on the ALB so that it waits as long as the MarkLogic appserver timeout and/or look on MarkLogic logs for signs of trouble(errors, bad response codes, RequestLog entries) - but if some requests are being made successfully, then it sounds like this question was answered. You have a Support ticket open with MarkLogic - update the status and work with them on this issue.
